# What does !!:2 mean in Mac or Linux?

Tags: bash, shell

Today I saw a command in Mac:

```
touch !!:2/{f1.txt, f2.txt}
```

I know the use of touch command but what does !!:2 does in this command. I don't have Mac and tried in Linux It is giving some weird output. If anyone could explain more expression like this it would be great.

Comment: The expression you ask about in the title is different than the one in the body. If you want to ask about both, then both should probably be in the body.

Comment: @jww That was a typo but , now I could see that both has some special meaning

Comment: The [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) you have `{f1.txt, f2.txt}` will not expand because of the space after the comma. Is that the way the command was written? It is probably a mistake.

Comment: No just written here . Thanks for that info .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`touch` updates file timestamp (to current time, given no arguments)

`!!` is 'History expansion' operation, retrieving previous command from bash history log in this form (two exclamation dots), alias for '!-1'

`:2` is word specifier, retrieving 2nd command argument. E.g. if previous history command was `ls -l /tmp`, `!!:2` will render to '/tmp'

`{f1.txt,f2.txt}` is called 'Brace expansion'. Brace expansion requires single word string without unescaped white spaces (it's definitely a typo in the question). For example, `foo{bar,baz}` will be expanded to 'foobar foobaz'

So, let's assume we run bash command

```
ls -l /tmp
```

Now, `touch !!:2/{f1.txt,f2.txt}` will produce

```
touch /tmp/f1.txt /tmp/f2.txt
```

Comment: Note that brace expansion requires a single word starting and ending with braces. The space in the original question prevents brace expansion.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the note, missed to remove this whitespace

Answer (score 0):

https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html

!! refers to the previous command. This is a synonym for ‘!-1’.

:2 refers to the second argument.

So for example :

```
echo "content" > foo
cp foo bar
cat !!:2
```

Displays the content of bar.
!!:2 is the second argument of the previous command.
Which one was it in your example?